# Как вывести данные столбца, если в классе стоит аннотация @Transient

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Нужно вывести данные столбца, в классе date_create, есть аннотация @Transient. Если ее убрать то данные будут выводится, но тогда не будет заносится данные в столбец(дата и время)

Например
Так выводится:

```
    if(petit.getBlockger2016().getDate_change() != null) { aRow.createCell(46).setCellValue(petit.getBlockger2016().getDate_change().toString());}
    else{ aRow.createCell(46).setCellValue(""); }
```

Но уже с Date_create показывает пустоту

```
    if(petit.getBlockger2016().getDate_create() != null) { aRow.createCell(46).setCellValue(petit.getBlockger2016().getDate_create().toString());}
    else{ aRow.createCell(46).setCellValue(""); }
```

В SQL:

```
date_change  DATE
date_create  DATE Default - sysdate
```

.java

```
private String date_create;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.S", timezone="GMT+6")
    private Date date_change;


    @Transient
    public String getDate_create() {
        return date_create;
    }

    public void setDate_create(String date_create) {
        this.date_create = date_create;
    }



    public Date getDate_change() {
        return date_change;
    }

    public void setDate_change(Date date_change) {
        this.date_change = date_change;
    }


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BlockGER2016 [idblockger2016=" + idblockger2016 + ", date_end=" + date_end + ", date_close="
            + date_close + ", letter_out_num=" + letter_out_num
            + ", letter_out_date=" + letter_out_date + ", regsource_id="
            + regsource_id + ", regname=" + regname + ", regnum=" + regnum
            + ", date_create=" + date_create + ", date_change="
            + date_change + ",inbound_from="+ inbound_from +",date_plan_end="+ date_plan_end +",claim_inshur="+ claim_inshur +"typempid="+typempid+" state=" + state + ",filecall ="+ filecall +"]";
}
```

.jsp

С аннотацией @Transient данные не выводятся

```
<td>  ${petit.blockger2016.date_create}</td>
```

Comment: Вы наверняка что-то путаете. Всё должно выводится. jsp по барабану Ваш transient. Просто data_create == null. Не видно где оно принимает значение, не равное null.
Быть может Вы думаете, что data_create загружается из базы данных? Тем не менее это не так. Читайте внимательнее о @Transient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, чего Вы хотите, то правильный ответ будет такой.
`@Transient` **заставляет полностью игнорировать свойство системой персистентности.

Ничего из него не сохраняет в базу, и ничего в него не загружает из базы.**
Поэтому Ваш `data_create` всегда пустой.

`@Transient` не годится.
Если хотите загружать данные из базы, но не хотите их туда записывать, то поступают примерно так

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String getDate_create() {
    return date_create;
}
```

Т.е. даётся указание не вставлять и не обновлять поле. Но извлекать ещё можно.

Но это ещё не всё. У новой записи будет проставлено время, но у нового объекта нет. Нужно каким-то образом обновлять новые объект, чтобы в них попали данных, которые генерирует бд. Никогда не интересовался, есть ли средства автоматизации сего действия, но в крайнем случае поможет стандартный refresh после persist/merge.
Но это на мой взгляд не очень хорошо.
На всякий случай предложу свой вариант установки времени создания/изменения.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    ...
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    ...

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }
    ...

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist {
        created = new Date();
        updated = created;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate {
        updated = new Date();
        if (created == null) { // на всякий случай
            created = updated;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Т.е. установка временных отметок осуществляется не бд, а приложением с помощью специальных обработчиков событий жизненного цикла сущности (`@PrePersist` и `@PreUpdate`).

Пару слов об SQL
Может не все ещё знают, что на самом деле значит `date_create  DATE Default - sysdate`
Может кто-то думает, что если попытаться записать `NULL` в `date_create`, то SQL запишет туда `sysdate`? Так вот, это не так. SQL послушно запишет туда `NULL`:)
На самом деле `sysdate` будет записано только если в запросе нет вообще никакого упоминания поля `date_create`.

Когда нет злосчастного `@Transient`, тогда формируется примерно такой запрос к бд:
`insert into my_table (id, data_create, name, ...) values (1, NULL, 'вася', ...)`
или такой
`insert into my_table (id, data_create, name, ...) values (1, '25/06/2021', 'вася', ...)`
в зависимости от того чем заполнены свойства объекта.
и поле `data_create` получает значение из запроса, каковым бы оно не было.

Теперь поставим `@Transient` на data_create, тогда запрос будет таким
`insert into my_table (id, name, ...) values (1, 'вася', ...)`
`data_create` в запросе мы больше не видим. Не видит его и бд, и записывает в поле `data_create` его `default`, т.е. `sysdate`

Рассмотрим обратный поток данных из бд в объекты-сущности.
Пусть нет `@Transient`. Тогда запрос будет примерно таким
`select id, data_create, name, ... from my_table`
Т.е. видим, что из базы извлекается поле `data_create` и его значение будет записано в одноимённое свойство объекта и показано на страничке.

Опять вернём `@Transient`. Честно говоря, не знаю как поведёт себя hibernate, но предполагаю запрос будет таким
`select id, name, ... from my_table`
Т.е. значению для свойства `data_create` даже в принципе взяться не от куда. И соответственно на страничке видим не фигвам, конечно, но что-то похожее:)

Comment: Запись нужна в БД. Но обновлять ее не нужно, как раз @Transient это делает.

Comment: Когда я убираю @Transient и в БД в столбце также находится sysdate - то поле пустое. И еще данный столбец с данными.

Comment: @wq55 но Вы хотите, чтобы было напечатана `data_create` из базы? своим `@Transient` Вы перекрываете и обратную дорожку из базы в объект. И поэтому поле в объекте остаётся пустым

Comment: А когда Вы убираете `@Transient`, то в базу действительно будет записан null. Я же показал один способ как туда записать нужные данные.

Comment: В Transient,  в БД в столбце также находится sysdate - то при занесении данных поле пустое, и тогда js может выводить данный столбец. Когда @Transient стоит в классе у date_create столбец данными проставляется, конечно вместе с sysdate. И еще данный столбец с данными.

Comment: Да убираю @Transient данные не заносятся проверил

Comment: @wq55 На самом деле заносятся, но они == null. Вот Вам и кажется, что не заносятся:) Надо зрить в корень, как учили предки. Есть даже средства трассировки запросов sql. Чтобы смотреть не только результат, но и все действия. Где уж точно видно что заносится, а что нет.

Comment: Да это понятно что, @Transient используется для обозначения полей, которые не должны сохраняться, т.е. сохранение происходит за счет БД в поле в defult указан sysdate. Что тогда можно сделать?

Comment: @wq55 в ответе собственно есть один вариант

Comment: Спасибо Большое